# Deleting a temporary DLL used in unit testing in C#

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, dll

I have a function, `addFromXML()`, that loads an XML file, parses it for DLLs paths, and loads those DLLs. These DLLs are CLR-based assemblies (not native code) that I wrote in other projects

In order to test it, I have multiple unit test functions that, during preparation, copy an example XML file and a stub DLL file from my Resources to a temporary file using `Path.getTempPath()`, then runs the tests.

Normally, I could delete the files after the test is completed in a finally block. However, DLLs are problematic because they cannot be deleted once loaded into the current AppDomain, so I would have to delete the DLLs manually after each test run has completed. If I don't, my temporary folder may increase in size more and more everytime I unit test, which is what I'm trying to reduce. Other people in my development team will also face the same issue if they run unit tests and I don't want that.

The only method of releasing the DLL is to load it in a separate AppDomain. However, I do not want to do that for my program because it overcomplicates matters and might affect performance. The ability to unload DLLs is also not a requirement for the actual program itself.

Perhaps my approach of copying the DLL to a temporary file is wrong? Is there a better way of testing loader functions that involve DLLs?

Answer (score 2):

What you are writing is not strictly a unit test. An ideal unit test would be robust and as such should not touch the file system.

If you are interested in maximising unit test coverage, a good approach might be to wrap the file copy .NET call and test that it is being called with the correct DLL paths. This would allow you to asset copy is being called without creating fragile unit tests that other members of your team will all have to learn about and set up.

You can also test the DLLs are loaded by including a sample DLL in your Unit test project and loading it during a unit test. This won't require moving things on the file system and won't be subject to the constraints you have.

Aim to make your unit tests only test your code, not the .NET framework, your hard disk, or your network. Your team and those who come after you will thank you for it. I hope that is helpful.

Comment: I understand that a unit test is supposed to be robust and that it's kinda ugly that I'm using temporary files, but I'm definitely testing my code, and not the .NET framework or the hard disk or the filesystem. What I meant by .NET assemblies is that they are CLR based assemblies I wrote, not from the .NET framework (I edited my question to clarify). I previously included a DLL in my unit test project and tried to have the unit test use that, but figuring out how to reference the files easily from within the unit test in a portable and correct manner was difficult. Perhaps I should try again.

Answer (score 1):

You could delete the previous dlls before the tests run instead, ie do the clean up before the test run rather than after. That way the previous dlls won't be loaded into the app domain and they can safely be removed. You will still have 1 runs worth of dlls, but that shouldn't be too big a deal.

Comment: I thought of this, but because I'm using random pathnames to avoid conflicts, this is probably not practical... unless I opt to use hardcoded path names for the temporary file, which may cause conflicts

Comment: what you could do is in the test fixture tear down you could output the name of the random file(s) you used in a file like CompletedTestRuns.txt, then when you start up read the contents of this file and delete all the files it indicates are not used any more. then you could remove the pointers from this file and start the tests.